# (pyramid xpa-240)if i had 10 voltage extra to a amplifiers what will happen?

Tags: voltage, control

[image: pyramid xpq-240]
I have a pyramid xpa-240 amplifier that does work with 110/220 voltage i want to know if it ok to use on 240 voltage? Or is the voltage to much for the amplifier?

Comment: What does its manual say?  I see 120V/60Hz, 230V 50 Hz  https://manualzz.com/doc/3403954/pyramid-car-audio-xpa-240-user-s-manual  So 240V might too much. Is the amplified fused for protection against over current with too high a voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By law, for safety, the voltage and power specs are near the AC power entry.

Notice the protected slide switch says 115 or 230V nom.  Just use the correct position and your expected difference input is less than the usual 10% tolerance. (+-23V)  It would only mean a slight increase in surge current when powering on.

If you experience frequent power interruptions from poor power quality in your area, perhaps some protection could be added like MOV found on most power bars for surge voltage and maybe consider adding an ICL for inrush current limiter.  (guestimate 10A)

[image]